# How to use string.Substring(char, char) instead string.Substring(int, int)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, substring, extension-methods

I made the extension method that returns a string between `leftChar` and `rightChar`:

```cs
    public static string Substring(this string This, char leftChar, char rightChar)
        {
            int i_left = This.IndexOf(leftChar);
            if (i_left >= 0)
            {
                int i_right = This.IndexOf(rightChar, i_left);
                if (i_right >= i_left)
                {
                    return This.Substring(i_left + 1, i_right - i_left - 1);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

When I invoke it up like this:

```cs
    string str = "M(234:342);".Substring('(', ')');
```

I get the exception:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: startIndex не может быть больше,
>   чем длина строки. Имя параметра: startIndex    в
>   System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)

The namespace of the extension method and the invoking code is correct. IntelliSense suggest me 3 extension methods (two basic and one mine).

> (extension) string string.Substring(char leftChar, char rightChar)

It is clear that `string.Substring(int startIndex, int Length)` overlaps with my extension method because the compiler casts char to int automaticaly.

**Is there a way to force the compiler not to do the cast `char` to `int`?**

---

- If I rename the extension method (like `Substring2`) all works.
- If I change `chars` to `params char[]`, it does not work, if I invoke it like params, but of course works like array.
- If I delete the extension method, `"M(234:342);".Substring('(', ')')` does not throw any compilation error, but still throw the exception.
- If I change `chars` to `strings` in the extension method it also works. This is my current favorite solution for this issue - to combine my `Substring(char, char)` with `Substring(string, string)` with checking lengths of input strings.

Comment: Note: there's no interpreter in .NET. There's the runtime, and the compiler. In this case you're interested in the compiler.

Comment: Another note: I'd strongly encourage you to follow .NET naming conventions, so use `camelCase` for parameter names.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you. I misspelled that. Sorry, English is not my native language.

Answer (score 11):

> Is there a way to force the interpreter not to do the cast char to int?

No. When it encounters a method invocation executed against a target expression, the compiler first checks whether any instance methods on the target's declared type are compatible with the arguments. It only looks for extension methods if there are *no* compatible methods.

In your case, the regular `string.Substring(int, int)` method is compatible with arguments `(char, char)` because of the implicit conversion from `char` to `int`.

The simplest solution is to rename your extension method - something like `SubstringBetween` perhaps.